# why few operators cannot be overloaded?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am having a doubt in the concept of Operator Overloading in C#.
We can overload few operators and few cannot be overloaded.
Is there any special reason for restricting few operators to be overloaded.
If so can any one explain me the reason.

Comment: Which operators do you *want* to overload which you can't?

Comment: Why do you mean by "few"? Which operators are you actually talking about?

Comment: i read that ?: and assigment operators cannot be overloaded but why cant we do that?
Actually i am interested in knowing the reason why these operators are restricted from being overloaded

Comment: @G_S: What would it *mean* to overload `?:`? Ditto assignment, really... you can overload conversion operators, which can end up being used in assignment statements...

Comment: It is how it is defined - [7.2.2 Operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). In general SO is for answering concrete questions - so if you have a particular useful case for something like "overload as" please specify, otherwise it likely to be closed...

Comment: Thanks for replying . I dont think this is really that bad question which should be closed or downvoted. Anywayz thanks for the answers

Comment: The conditional operator (?:) operates on a boolean. It's difficult to see a use case for overloading it.

Comment: Can i know what this means? Its difficult to see a use case for overloading it?

Comment: Why would you do that? What purpose would it serve?

Comment: No i just want to know why that's restricted.. not what's the purpose of doing that.

Comment: G_S, try to write down behavior of "overloaded `?: operator`". Do it purely for yourself, no cheating on ignoring corner cases. Don't forget at least basic cases of value and reference types, nullable types, if have special handling for string/arrays is needed. Don't forget relation to implicit/explicit casts, make sure to cover return type... Than read resulting description - if it results in "who on earth would be able to understand that" - here is your answer...

Comment: Oops thanks @AlexeilLevenkov.. I think this would answer my question perfectly.. Thanks a lot.. What i understood was when the ?: operator works with almost all the types what's the need of still overloading it.
Is that what i understood is correct? Please correct if i am wrong

Comment: I was trying to show that if explanation of behavior is longer than couple sentences (which is always the case when you allow custom behavior, including rules to pick correct overloaded behavior) it requires *very* good reasons to be included in the language. I.e. "+" and other math operator have very clear meaning for "algebraic types" (numbers, vectors, matrix...) - so there is a good reason to allow overloads. `?:` or `.` on other hand have no defined behavior outside programing - much weaker case to allow overload.

Comment: So its just better to overload an operator only if there is really a good reason for it... That's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason has to do with the fact the references can only have one set of behavior in C#.  You should have searched [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599367/why-can-not-be-overloaded-in-c).  It's a great site for questions like this one ;)

This post only deals with the assignment operator, but operators like ?: also deal with references, so they also cannot be overloaded.

Comment: **This question was asked on Stack Overflow**

Comment: Hello Ramhound,
The ;) indicated a joke, since we are aware we are on Stack Overflow.